# On which site should I ask about an alternative to Google App Engine.

Tags: discussion, scope, site-recommendation

I asked [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/135407/do-you-know-of-any-alternative-to-google-app-engine) on Super User and my question was closed as off-topic. Can anyone please help  me determine where I should ask this question?

Here is the question:

> "On their presentation of "Google App
>   Engine" Google team members boldly
>   said: "You write a code and we will
>   run it for you". Then the "Google App
>   Engine" was launched and it still does
>   its job quite successfully - "Google
>   App Engine" runs millions of
>   applications of different sizes
>   belonging to different users
>   completely free!!!
>
> Now, here is the question: Do You know
>   of any alternative to GAE? Have You
>   ever even heard of any such service
>   out there that would run Your Python
>   code for free?"

Comment: possible duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41570/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-arent-super-user-questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The existing answer to this question is no longer correct. Now that the Stack Exchange network has welcomed [Web Applications](http://webapps.stackexchange.com) to the family, there is a place for your question. There's a whole tag just for "is there an app that does ..."-style questions, actually.

Comment: WOW!!! Thank You very much for this information!!!

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately... there's nowhere to ask this. SuperUser, for better or for worse, only allows questions on software you install and run on your own PC. I imagine as web software becomes even more prevalent this may be revised.

If your angle is a "I'm programming and something doesn't work on GAE...", then StackOverflow might take it, but unfortunately you've hit that grey area that the trilogy just doesn't cover.